# Set reminder for next boot

Tags: gratis, windows-7, reminders

I am looking for a program that allows me to set a reminder *before* I shut down the computer (in the night), and when the computer next turns on (in the morning), I am presented with a friendly reminder so I can do whatever I needed to.

Requirements:

- free
- runs on Windows 7 64 bit
- quick and easy (I open a program, type some text, click 'save' or similar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any installation you can use on Windows 7 64-bit, the included "Sticky notes tool" or at your discretion the side bar gadget.

For example:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, I create a sticky note, and the sticky note reopens on next boot?

Comment: @ṧнʊß No, it always stays on the desktop.

Comment: @ComFreek So it's a sticky note, that never goes away (even if you shut down) until you say so? I also see that Nick's edited this - it's built in, so I'll try it.

Comment: Although I wasn't thinking of a solution like this, it does what I want!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) that is included with Windows since Windows 98:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler :

> In addition to the graphical user interface for Task Scheduler in
>   Control Panel, Windows provides two command-line tools for managing
>   scheduled task: at.exe (deprecated) and schtasks.exe. However, at.exe
>   cannot access tasks created or modified by Control Panel or
>   schtasks.exe. Also, tasks created with at.exe are not interactive by
>   default; interactivity needs to be explicitly requested.

[Schtasks documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx)

Comment: I forgot to say - quick and easy. Literally a few minutes before I  shutdown the computer. Do you know of an option where you open a program, enter some text, and click 'save' or something?

Comment: @ṧнʊß No, sorry. The Task Scheduler is pretty easy but yes has a bunch of options around.

Comment: Yeah, it's easy but not very quick! +1 for the option though. I'll wait for other solutions!

Comment: One could register a scheduled task via [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649816.aspx). However, the documentation mentions PowerShell 4.0, which is only built-in in Windows 8.1. It needs to be installed on [Windows 7](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx).

Comment: I was just editing the answer to mention that in addition to the graphical user interface for Task Scheduler in Control Panel, Windows provides two command-line tools for managing scheduled task: at.exe (deprecated) and schtasks.exe :)

Comment: @ṧнʊß `shutdown /s /t 600` in a bat script would generate a notification that a shutdown was scheduled to occur in 10 minutes. You would then ahve 10 minutes to do a `shutdown /a` in a command prompt to abort.

Comment: @AWippler Sorry, I don't understand. Why do I need to schedule a shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

As per the suggestion from Franck you could use the `schtasks` executable from a batch file, *maybe called remindme.bat*, with all of the parameters pre-filled in:

- `/SC ONLOGON` should schedule the task for at log-on.
- `/Z` should delete the task once run once
- `/TR c:\Windows\System32\msg.exe * "%*"` should put the reminder you supply into the messenger *there may be some work needed with the quotes.*